# Does Vagrant 1.7.*. support VirtualBox 5.x?

Tags: centos, virtualbox, vagrant

I have installed VirtualBox 5.0.2r102096. Previously I had VirtualBox 4.3.*. 
Vagrant version is Vagrant 1.7.2, but when I do

```
vagrant up
```

it was giving me following error:

```
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:
```

There was a suggestion on [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717428/vagrant-error-failed-to-mount-folders-in-linux-guest)
to upgrade VirtualBox, so I upgraded. 
Now I am getting the following error when I do
`vagrant up`:

```
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

Vagrant has detected that you have a version of VirtualBox installed
that is not supported. Please install one of the supported versions
listed below to use Vagrant:

4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3
```

How can I rectify the above errors?

Comment: What is the question here? If virtualbox 5 is supported by your version of vagrant? In that case you provide the answer in the question. Furthermore, you don't mention which version of vagrant you're using.

Comment: @Marco thanks for pointing out, I have updated question, please see it ?

Comment: Ensure you use the [latest version of Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html). This problem occurs in version 7.2 but is fixed in 7.4

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm upgrading to (reinstalling) Vagrant v.1.7.4 fixed the errors.
https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/installation/index.html

There was a pull request that fixed it for the later versions than 1.7.2.
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5572